# Leverage browser caching not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

im building a new site and i'm trying to improve its speed and page rank. One of the problems i have is Leverage browser caching. I've read online different solutions, but none of them seems to work for me. I edited the .htaccess file and added the following code:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I still cannot fix the error. Also, Gtmetrix report shows that the problem is only with my front page images. (I'm using wordpress and front page is a static page).
Is there a way to add expiry header to specific files by location ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

That codes works only in apache service.
please inter your website address.
for more information:
https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved it. You have to enable mod_expires module. Have a look on my answer :- [Leverage browser caching not working - Htaccess & mod_expires Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465684/leverage-browser-caching-not-working-htaccess-mod-expires-active/#answer-44222212)